# Server won't come up with no video card

Tags: windows-server-2012, supermicro, intel-amt

> Preface: I know that this is a strange question, but I've been pulling
>   my hair out trying to figure this out. I'm getting an old PCI card
>   this weekend and leaving it in, but until then I'm going to rail
>   against it, just because it's annoying me. Any help would be appreciated.

I've got a whitebox server at my house that consists of the following:

- SuperMicro SC846E16-1200B chassis
- SuperMicro X10SAE Motherboard
- Intel Xeon E3-1231v3
- 16GB of Crucial ECC RAM
- LSI 9207-4i4e HBA in IT mode
- 2x HGST 1TB 2.5" drives in on-board RAID1 (OS Drive)
- 2x WD RED 4TB 3.5" drives on the SAS Backplane (will put more, but just have these two for testing now)
- I use a Radeon 6950 (only thing I had laying around) to do initial setup
- WS2012R2 - currently in Server Core, but I've tried the full GUI as well
- Intel AMT is provisioned (no KVM since no IGP, but I can get the event logs and do remote power management and stuff)

Okay, so here's behavior the system is exhibiting. I configured the BIOS and installed the OS with the video card in. I'd then like to take the video card out and use it headless. Once I take the video card out, the OS refuses to come up. If I check the AMT event logs, they look identical for a successful boot with the video card in and for an unsuccessful boot with the video card out.

This is the most recent unsuccessful boot:

[image: This is the most recent unsuccessful boot]

This is the most recent successful boot:

[image: This is the most recent successful boot]

However, the Windows event logs show nothing on the unsuccessful boot, not even a kernel power event. (I'd pull them but it's currently off)

As far as BIOS settings go, I have the Prompt on Error set to Off, as well as enabled Serial Port redirection (this was causing a warning in the AMT event logs about missing a video device, which is gone now - obviously it didn't help though). I'm no BIOS expert or anything but I've checked the settings for anything that might be related to this to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Also I just realized this should probably be in Super User. Is it possible to move the post. or do I have to delete it and re-create?